# Using Selenium, how to get method and selector of element which is not found?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium WebDriver and Java, I'm trying to get parent element or element around an element which results into `NoSuchElementException` and want to highlight other element in screenshot.

When element is not found, it results into `NoSuchElementException` with message -

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@role='menubar']/li[contains(@class,'youarehere')]"}
```

Out of above message, is there any best way to get method and selector using apis?

I can achieve that by parsing string following way but looking for any other easy out of the box api.

```
try {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@role='menubar']//li[contains(@class,'youarehere')]"));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            String locator = e.getMessage().split("Unable to locate element: ")[1];
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(locator);
            String method = jsonObject.getString("method");
            String selector = jsonObject.getString("selector");
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting it right. but **Selenium 4**  has a new feature for finding relative locators like **toLeftOf()** **toRightOf()** **above()** and **below()**.

Comment: But those functions will work only when element is found. My case is where element is not found.

Comment: OK, now I got it.